# C++ macro gives C4430 error: Missing type specifier

Tags: c++, macros

I am following Google's C++ style guide which suggests: For classes, one should add the macro

```
#define DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(TypeName) \
  TypeName(const TypeName&);               \
  void operator=(const TypeName&) 

class MyClass {
...
DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(MyClass);
};

#undef DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN
```

I add this macro to a number of classes in my project. When I compile, I get the error:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the preprocessor output and ensure it's correct.

Comment: ... represents the class content.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/foqmNr). The problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @emre, I ask because there may be an error in the `...` part.

Comment: By the way, the Google style guide is generally considered to be poor among the C++ community.  However, a [talk at CppCon](http://sched.co/1lsTA3A) will be addressing this.

Comment: Thanks @Brian I just wanted to look at the macro part, I will further investigate the content.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I can't produce this for two simple classes either. I don't understand why :/

Comment: @chris google c++ guide may not be the best, but it was just there, you know :)

Comment: Alright, I'll say it.  I **disagree** with Google here.

Comment: Assignment operator must return TypeName&

Comment: @JohnDibling do you have a better idea?

Comment: @NetVipeC I don't think so.

Comment: @emre:  Yes.  Write the explicitly deleted member functions yourself, or derive from a class like `noncopyable`.  Anything but the macro.

Comment: Works on my side (gcc 4.9). Make sure your class defines a constructor, and also that you don't un-define the macros then use it again, in which case it will look like a member function with no return type.

Comment: Since i am including this macro in a group of files, one of them is un-defining it before the current file uses it, and this is the reason of my error, what do you think?

Comment: @emre, I believe this is the reason, i.e. undefining the macro.

Comment: @vsoftco I am not sure how to solve this problem, any ideas?

Comment: @emre, you can define the macro in a header surrounded by include guards, although I find the whole approach (with macros) quite obscure.

Comment: Why are you following that guide? "it was just there" is not a justification to refuse everything that makes C++ useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An error is in `...` part. Also It's better to `delete` your copy and assing operator not just hiding them

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
}
```

Note that `delete` is c++11 feature

Comment: Note that this will only work under C++11.  The Google Style guide predates that Standard.

Answer (score 2):

I do believe you're missing a semicolon here:

```
void operator=(const TypeName&)
```

Since this was downvoted, I'll prove it.

Here is your original code (with the `...` removed and some other stuff added in to make it actually compile your class), failing to compile:

```
#define DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(TypeName) \
  TypeName(const TypeName&);               \
  void operator=(const TypeName&) 

class MyClass {
public: MyClass()
:
  mN (42)
{
}

private:
  int mN; 
DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(MyClass)
  long mL; 
};

#undef DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN

int main()
{
  MyClass c;


}
```

Under G++4.8, the compiler complains:

```
jdibling@hurricane /home/jdibling/dev/hacks $ g++ main.cpp 
main.cpp:3:33: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
   void operator=(const TypeName&) 
                                 ^
main.cpp:14:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN’
 DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(MyClass)
 ^
```

If we edit the macro definition to include a semicolon:

```
#define DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(TypeName) \
  TypeName(const TypeName&);               \
  void operator=(const TypeName&);
```

It compiles clean:

```
jdibling@hurricane /home/jdibling/dev/hacks $ g++ main.cpp 
jdibling@hurricane /home/jdibling/dev/hacks $
```

Comment: I don't think this is the reason.

Comment: @Quest:  It doesn't work.  Remove the semicolon on line 7 and see what happens.  Then add a semicolon to line 3 and see what happens there.

Comment: @emre:  I'm pretty convinced this *is* the reason.  See my edit.

Comment: @JohnDibling yes I agree but he added `;` behind `DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(MyClass)` so it is not problem in this case.. at least i think so

Comment: Thanks for the effort @JohnDibling, but I still get the same error even if I do what you are saying.

Comment: @emre:  Show me a self-contained, small, fully-compilable example that I can test here.

Comment: @JohnDibling I will add 3 files content in the following contents.

Comment: Here they are:

http://speedy.sh/4AeWm/atom-group.h

http://speedy.sh/9KXwf/main.cpp

http://speedy.sh/AVc47/matrix.h